# How to fix reset pages every time I go to another page - ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I just want to ask how can I solve this problem? sorry I don't have enough knowledge about ReactJS and we have a project. (because we only do self study on our course T_T and it is really hard for me but we need it to finish out projects)

My problem is that Every time I go to other page it will reset vice versa.

when I go to [image] Todo list nav and add some task and when I go to [image]Pomodo timer Nav and go back again to todo list [image] it will reset the inside of todo list nav. I want to do when I add some tasks and change the time of my timer, it will stay the same.

Comment: Please google more about these topics: states, state management, mount and unmount. For your problem, it's expected. When you go to another page with new components, all previous components and its states will be discarded.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to store the already saved tasks (state of to do list) in state variable. And same for Timer. If you are already doing that and it still resets, then I assume that you have separate child components for these two. In that case, store the state (saved tasks) in the state variable in the parent component and pass down as props to the child component. That way, when timer is rendered in place of to do list, state will not be lost.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).